# JavaScript - mystery around `this` keyword

Tags: javascript

As per my understanding, if 'this' keyword is used in a function, then it always refers to the owner of the function. But in the following scenario why 'this' is not able to find the object property of the owner object -

```
var calledObj = {};
calledObj.objectProperty = 'calledObj property';
calledObj.calledMethod = function(){
  alert(this.objectProperty);
}

var callingObj = {
    objectProperty: 'callingObj property',
    callingMethod: function(callbackF){
        if(typeof callbackF !== 'function'){
          callbackF = false;
        }
        if(callbackF){              
          callbackF();
        }
    }
};
callingObj.callingMethod(calledObj.calledMethod); // alert 'UNDEFINED'
```

It should alert 'callingObj property', because 'callingMethod' belongs to 'callingObj' and 'callingObj' already has a 'objectProperty' property. Then why 'this' is not able to recognize it?

Comment: Yet another `this` question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript a function doesn't have a specific owner. One object or several objects can have a reference to the function, or no object at all.

The value of `this` inside the function depends only on how you call the function. If you use the period syntax to call it, or use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), the value of `this` is the object that you specify.

Example:

```
someObj.func(); // using period syntax the value for 'this' is someObj

func.call(someObj); // providing a value for 'this'
```

When you use the period syntax without calling the function, you just get the reference to the function, and it's not attached to the object. Calling the function using the reference will not provide a value for `this`, so the value will be the global context, i.e. the `window` object if the code runs in a browser.

Example:

```
var f = someObj.func; // get the reference

f(); // call the function without a value for 'this'

f.call(someObj); // call the function specifying a value for 'this'
```

Comment: Guffia, if I use 'this' in the func() method, then as per your comment, it will always points to a global object provided I am using the period syntax. If it is true, then if I use something like this `someObj.property="hello"; someObj.func = function(){alert(this.property)}; someObj.func()`, then it should alert `undefined`, because `property` is not present in global object

Comment: @YashGarg: Sorry for the confusion. If you use the period syntax, the value for `this` is the object where you got the function reference. I'll try to make that clearer in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the context, whatever that context may be.

As you write `callbackF()`, there is no context! You have dereferenced the function and therefore `this` is not what you expect.

`callbackF.call(calledObj);` will work, because this explicitly sets the context back to what you wanted it to be.

Comment: There's that word again, "context". The only relationship between context and *this* in ECMA-262 is in regard to [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), of which *this* is one parameter. A function's *this* is a parameter that can be set to any object by the call (or use of [*bind*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)), or to any value at all in strict mode. MDN has a pretty good article on [*this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Niet, so in this case, is it correct to say - 'this' refers to the 'global object'?

Comment: Yes, because the value of *this* is not set in the call. You could do: `callingObj.callingMethod(function(){calledObj.calledMethod()})` so that *this* is set to the required value and *callingObj* doesn't need to know anything about *calledObj* or *calledObj.calledMethod*, it just calls the function it's been passed, and that function sets *this*.